# C#, DataGridView not garbage collecting properly?

Tags: c#, datagridview, garbage-collection

I've been looking at this problem the last two days and I'm all out of ideas, so I'm hoping someone might have some insight into what exactly is going on.

In brief, the program loads in a CSV file (with 240K lines, so not a ton) into a DataGridView, does a bunch of different operations on the data, and then dumps it into an Excel file for easy viewing and graphic and what not.  However, as I iterate over the data in the DataGridView, ram usage constantly increases.  I trimmed down the code to the simplest form and it's still happened and I don't quite understand why.

```
try
        {
            string conStr = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=C:\Downloads;Extensions=csv,txt";
            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conStr);
            //OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from bragg2.csv", conn);
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from bragg4.csv", conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DudeYa");
            da.Fill(dt);

            dgvCsvFile.DataSource = dt;

            da.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        string sDeviceCon;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvCsvFile.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgvCsvFile.Rows[i].Cells[48].Value != DBNull.Value)
                sDeviceCon = (string)dgvCsvFile.Rows[i].Cells[48].Value;
            else
                sDeviceCon = "";

            if ((sDeviceCon == null) || (sDeviceCon == ""))
                continue;
        }
```

When I enter that for loop, the program is using 230 megs.  When I finish it, I'm using 3 gigs.  At this point I'm not even doing anything with the data, I'm literally just looking at it and then moving on.

Futhermore, if I add these lines after it:

```
dgvCsvFile.DataSource = null;
dgvCsvFile.Rows.Clear();
dgvCsvFile.Columns.Clear();
dgvCsvFile.Dispose();

GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
```

The RAM usage stays the same.  I can't figure out how to actually get the memory back without closing the program.

I've downloaded various memory profiling tools to try and figure out exactly whats going on:

Using VMMap from Sys Internals to take periodic snapshots, there were instances of the Garbage Collector running that were filling up.  Each later snapshot I took usually had more Garbage Collectors running with all the previous ones using ~260MB of ram.

Using .NET Memory Profiler, I was able to get a little bit more detailed information.  According to that, I have approximately 4 million instances of PropertyStore, DataGrieViewTextBoxCell and PropertyStore.IntegerEntry[].  All of them appear to have 1 reference and are existing uncollected in the Garbage Collector.

I ran the program in x86 mode and it caused an out of memory exception (not terribly unexpected).  It throws the error inside of  DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Clone(), which is in turn inside a DataGridViewRow.CloneCells() and DataGridViewRow.Clone().  So obviously it's doing a whole bunch of cloning to access the cell data... but why is it never being cleaned up?  What could possibly be holding onto the reference for them?

I also tried getting the data into the DataSource in a different way using the CachedCsvReader from LumenWorks.Framwork.IO with no change in the functionality.

Is there something that I'm missing?  Is there a setting I should be changing somewhere?  Why aren't any of these things being disposed of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!